# UITableView with multiple items in each cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview in which I am trying to place a button with an image and a label. I want to change the image of the button once clicked.

Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
checkedImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonUnChecked1.png"];

UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


//Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [suggestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

check = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
check.frame=CGRectMake(0,35,20,20);
[check setImage:checkedImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[check addTarget:self action:@selector(checkClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:check];

cellContent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,32,500,25)];
cellContent.text = cellValue;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellContent];
return cell;
}


-(void)checkClicked:(UIButton *)b
{
checkedImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonChecked1.png"];
[check setImage:checkedImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

By doing this, the image of the buttons are getting changed but only the last one and not the one clicked. I know the reason behind it, but I don't know how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer to your problem is to change your `checkClicked:` method to this:

```
-(void)checkClicked:(UIButton *)b
{
    [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonChecked1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But you should also adjust your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to avoid creating the button repeatedly and to clean up some memory issues like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    

UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIButton *checkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    checkBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,35,20,20);
    [checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonUnChecked1.png"]; forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBtn];

    UILabel *cellContentLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,32,500,25)];
    cellContentLbl.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellContentLbl];
    [cellContentLbl release];
}


//Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [suggestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellContent = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
cellContent.text = cellValue;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this code fail to reset a re-used cell's state? If you click on a cell's button, then scroll around, clicked buttons will appear where they shouldn't.

Comment: But there is one more problem, if the user taps it again it should get unchecked again.For this i changed my checkClicked method to this:        -(void)checkClicked:(UIButton *)b
{
 if (!checked) {
  [b setImage:checkedImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  checked = YES;
 }
 else {
  [b setImage:unCheckedImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

 
}
But now if after user unchecks a button and click another button its not working because of the Bool value changed to YES.

Comment: @Ashutosh my answer only fixes your immediate problem and doesn't solve the issues of your over all design. You are attempting to keep singular variables for multiple objects/values and this will never work. You can't have a single `checked` value that you use for all your buttons or a single button reference as both of these will only point to the last one checked or created (respectively). @Occulus answer is better in that it addresses the real problem - your design. Please accept his answer (feel free to give me an upvote though :) ) and work with him to hash out a better solution.

Comment: re: my earlier comment about failing to reset a re-used cell's state -- please see the prepareForReuse method in UITableViewCell for a nice way to do this.

Comment: @Ashutosh If you want to know about structuring your solution in a better way, see my answer. That's what I was telling you about.

Answer (score 3):

A structured way to get the result you're looking for:

Make a UIView subclass that for your table cells (containing a button and label). You instantiate these custom views and set them as your `contentView` for each table cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Each of your custom views listens for its own button being pressed. When it was pressed, it toggles its state and tells the main viewcontroller (via a delegate method) that it was toggled. The main view controller calls reloadData on the cell in question to cause it to be reloaded with the correct appearance.

Note that this approach requires you to tell each of the custom views which index path it is rendering for in the table -- that way it can inform the main view controller's delegate method -- this info is needed for triggering a reload of the appropriate cell.

Btw, I presume you want to look at the state of the buttons in your table when the user is done with editing, and your current approach doesn't capture the state stuff very explicitly -- you'd have to iterate over your buttons, or add selected items to a mutable array, or something.